# How to get specified pages range from pdf in Java?

Tags: java, pdf

I have big (about 1000 pages) pdf file. Is some Java API/Library to extract for example 6-10 page from that pdf (as new pdf file) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use PDFBox .

http://pdfbox.apache.org/

Answer (score 2):

I've done that with [iText](http://itextpdf.com/itext.php)